# Is there any way post RFC 1123 formated date in the HTTP date header in dot net

Tags: c#, .net, date, http, rfc1123

I am trying to invoke service which is expecting  RFC 1123 formatted date in the Request header using C#.

I using the bellow code:-

```
var req = WebRequest.Create(loginDdsLink) as HttpWebRequest;
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Method = "POST";
req.Accept = "*/*";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000;
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Date,  Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R"))));
```

The last line is throwing exception because HttpRequestHeader.Date is expecting DateTime but i am passing String.
Is there any way to send the String value in the HttpRequestHeader.Date parameter?

Comment: RFC 1123 mandates a base64 encoded version of the date? o_O

Comment: no,if I try with bellow code then also getting same issue.                req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Date,  dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R")); I tried the bellow too, but getting compiler error. req.Date = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R");